# PHP Array Retrieve Value

Tags: php

When I run this:

```
print_r($Result);
```

I get the following:

**stdClass Object ( [SendMessageWithReferenceResult] => Message queued successfully )**

How can I assign the "Message queued successfully" as a variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a little hard to tell from your question, but I think it would just be:

```
$variable = $Result->SendMessageWithReferenceResult;
```